# Get custom error message with Ajax form

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using an ajax form with this initialization on the view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditUser", "Admin", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "AddEditSuccessul",
    OnFailure = "AddEditFailed",
    OnBegin = "HideModalEditUser"
}, new { @id = "MainForm" }))
```

And it works quite well. I would like to add a message to the `AddEditFailed` to warn the user about *why* the operation failed. I tried to edit the code to:

```
OnFailure = "AddEditFailed(message)",
```

And put `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(code, "Custom message.");` in the controller. I also adapted the JS to:

```
function AddEditFailed(message)
{
    swal({
        title: "Error",
        text: "Details : " + message,
        type: "error",
        showCancelButton: false,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "OK",
        closeOnConfirm: true
    });
}
```

But I get the error:

> ReferenceError: message is not defined

Is there a way to do it without changing the whole mechanism or am I in the obligation to refactor the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature for the function is OnFailure(xhr, status, error).
It is strange that message is undefined. There should be your xhr request.

Oh it seems that you should change your code to
 `OnFailure = "AddEditFailed(xhr, status, 'Person')"`
Check out [this post](http://johnculviner.com/ajax-beginform-ajaxoptions-custom-arguments-for-oncomplete-onsuccess-onfailure-and-onbegin/)

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds!